# PHP not showing the values in MySQL in the table for Select Box and Text Area

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Information.php

```
<?php

if (empty($_POST)===false){
    $required_fields = array('first_name','last_name','gender','age','location','about_me');
    foreach($_POST as $key =>$value){
        if(empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true){
            $errors = 'fillin';
            break 1;
        }
    }
}
if (empty($_POST)=== false && empty($errors) === true){

    $update_data = array(
        'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
        'gender' => $_POST['gender'],
        'age' => $_POST['age'],
        'location' => $_POST['location'],
        'about_me' => $_POST['about_me']
    );
    update_user($update_data);
    echo 'updated';
}else if (empty($errors) === false){
    echo $errors;
}
?>
        <form action = "" method = "POST">
        First Name: <input type = "text" name = "first_name" maxlength = "40" placeholder = "First Name" value = "<?php echo $user_data['first_name']; ?>"><br>
        Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "last_name" maxlength = "40" placeholder = "Last Name" value = "<?php echo $user_data['last_name']; ?>"><br>
        Gender: <select type = "text" name = "gender" value = "<?php echo $user_data['gender']; ?>"><option>Select</option><option name = "male" value = "Male">Male</option><option name = "female" value = "Female">Female</option><option name = "othergen" value = "Other">Other</option></select><br>
        Age: <input type = "text" name = "age" maxlength = "3" placeholder = "What's your age?" value = "<?php echo $user_data['age']; ?>"><br>
       Location: <input type = "text" name = "location" maxlength = "100" placeholder = "Your location?" value = "<?php echo $user_data['location']; ?>"><br>
        About Me: <textarea type = "text" name = "about_me" maxlength = "500" placeholder = "Say something about yourself!" value = "<?php echo $user_data['about_me']; ?>"></textarea><br>

        <input type = "submit" value = "submit">
        </form>
```

Main problem is that it is not showing the value of the textarea and the select box which I manually updated through PHPmyadmin, but it shows the ones in the textboxs just fine.

UPDATE: The fields are now updating successfully! Even the text area and selectboxs are updated in the table. However, the value is not showing in the textarea or in the select box. So the problem still persists!

variable user_data:

```
$user_data = user_data($session_user_id,'user_id','username','password','first_name','last_name','email','gender','age','location','about_me');
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: Gender: <select type = "text" name = "gender" value = "<?php echo $user_data['gender']; ?>"><option>Select</option> This is wrong! The select does not have a value, the option has one, and you access the selected option value from by the name of the select field. To update, you have to test each option against the current value.

Comment: In the code you provided you are not actually calling the function update_user() anywhere so I am not surprised that the table is not updated

Comment: @Pankrates Ya, I jsut realized it. I changed the topic but I still have another problem!

Comment: The html code probably does not cause the error, please provide the php code where you set the $user_data variable and print_r its contents

Comment: Did you try like this, -- echo strip_tags($user_data['about_me']); --

Comment: @Pankrates I have provided the code! The problem is that the update is not showing in the select box or in the textarea. It shows nothing there!

Comment: Therefore I need to see what the variable $user_data contains, please show the php code where that variable is set, so not! the update code which you have shown currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As defined by the W3C, [textarea](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.7) does not have a `value` attribute. Instead, the value is wrapped by the `<textarea></textarea>` tags

```
<TEXTAREA name="thetext" rows="20" cols="80">
    First line of initial text.
    Second line of initial text.
</TEXTAREA>
```

This is also valid for the document type [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html)

A `<select>..</select>` will always submit the first `<option>` by default. If you want to preselect another option, you have to add the attribute `selected="selected"` to this option.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6.1

Select does not have a type attribute.

Example: how to add the `selected` attribute in a PHP template

```
<select name="fieldname">
    <option value="on select,submitted value" <?php echo $myValue == 'on select,submitted value' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>displayed value</option>
    <option value="on select,submitted value 2" <?php echo $myValue == 'on select,submitted value 2' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>displayed value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, what about the select box. I got the text area!